# Is Facebook Connect encouraging users to signup?

Tags: signup-signon, facebook-connect

If you have 2 websites, one with Facebook Connect button prominent on the homepage, the other one displays Facebook only if you click or mouseover on signup link/button.

Do you think people will more likely signup on the first website just because of the Facebook button?

> like: "great there is a Facebook Connect! I signup."

Or at the opposite, the value proposition of your website should be strong enough to encourage users to signup and then provide the conveniency of Facebook Connect at that time.

PS: Some of you will probably tell me that it is better to have the Facebook button right away, but the underlying theme of this question is having a good balance between minimal design and conveniency.

Comment: We don't have problems with Facebook login. We have problems with hiding options from users and calls for opinions. It would be great if you rephrased your question to fix 2 problems: 1) call for opinions and 2) unclear comparison between FB login and something else (what is the alternative?).

Comment: I think **the context is necessary to evaluate its effectiveness**. It is hard to generally say that users are more likely or less likely to sign up on a website because there is an option to sign up with Facebook.

Comment: Personally, I hate the Facebook connect button, especially for comments, and if alternative methods are too difficult/hidden. Perhaps I don't want to associate every single comment I make with my real identity (and friends list etc.)?

Comment: @dbkk - That is where context comes in. The nature of the site is very relevant to the question of if Facebook integration is a good fit. That said, I do agree having the option to NOT use Facebook is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People will not signup to a bad site simply because it supports Facebook/Twitter/Google's authentication mechanism.  (I don't know your site so this is not implying anything about your site... :) )

That being said, I think it is safe to leave the FB Connect buttons on the user registration page because at that point they've "expressed" an interest in actually signing up and it should lessen the friction of the sign up process.

Answer (score 0):

Push users to sign up for your site, but have secondary options to connect via another network if they choose.